# jQuery stop infinite scroll triggering untill next page is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, infinite-scroll

i use this to make an infinite scroll in my custom wordpress tempate, i put the button that does the ajax in the bottom of the page and i need it there, then i use this to trigger that button when the user is almost scrolled to the down of the page:

```
<script>
  // Infinite scroll script
  $(function() {
    $('.st-content').on('scroll', function() {  
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').trigger('click');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The problem i'm facing is that the event keeps triggering before the ajax request is done.. causing the event to crash. is there a way to prevent calling the trigger function until the previous ajax request is done?

Comment: Can you add here the call to the ajax function ?

Comment: This is it: https://jsfiddle.net/bpusxpmq/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind your event in the success of the ajax call :

```
  $('.pbd-alp-placeholder-' + pageNum).load(nextLink + ' .filter',
      function() {
          $('.st-content').on('scroll', function() {
              if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
                  $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').trigger('click');
              }
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

Use a global variable to track current action;

```
<script>
  // Infinite scroll script

  /* allow loading data */
  var canLoad = true;
  $(function(){
    $('.st-content').on('scroll', function(){
      /* chack for last ajax request finished or not */
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100 && canLoad){
        /* Disable next load till current in progress. */
        canLoad = false;
        $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').trigger('click');
      }
    });
  });

  /**
   * @todo set canLoad = false in $.ajax complete
   */

  $.ajax({
    /* your rest ajax options here */
    complete:function(){
      canLoad = true;
    }
  });
</script>
```